# How can I get a list of the days in a year and follow this form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, miniconda

This code not work at all, and I'm still confusing with the pandas datetime method...

```
def date_list():

    list = []

    for i in pd.date_range(datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 12, 31)):

        list.append(datetime[1], datetime[2])
    return list
```

This is the example for the list, and should I use zfill method for making this list?(If it's leap year)
  [0101, 0102, 0103, ..., 1230, 1231]

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve]. "not work" doesn't help us.

Comment: I add a example, idk why the image didn't show up...

Comment: Don't do it as an image. The error message needs to be in the post itself.

Comment: What is `datetime[1]` supposed to do?  Why are you passing two arguments to `list.append`?

Comment: I think I can do slice to the datetime object, like mm/dd/yyyy, I only want to keep the mmdd part.

Comment: Do you just want `pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31').strftime('%m%d')`? Or  `pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31').strftime('%m%d').tolist()` for a python list instead of a numpy array.

Comment: OMG, got it! Thank you soooooo much! XD

Comment: Okay, I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) to directly do the formatting:

```
dt_list = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31').strftime('%m%d')
```

Use [`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) if you want a Python list instead of a numpy array:

```
dt_list = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31').strftime('%m%d').tolist()
```